# How can I locate a custom overlays inside streetview?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, custom-overlay

Hi I have searched for all the web and stackoverflow.

Anyone knows how to locate a custom overlay in a specific position inside  Google maps street view ?

Here are an example :

[Night Walk](https://nightwalk.withgoogle.com/en/home)

In this tour you can see that there are some icons and items located in specific locations .

Does anyone know how to do that ? This is amazing and I want know how to do it.

I have experience with Google maps javascript API, but I can not do this.

---

I solved this with this library https://github.com/marmat/google-maps-api-addons

This is the result : http://www.paneek.net/#/home

Answer (score 1):

I found this while looking how to achieve a similar thing:

- http://projects.teammaps.com/projects/streetviewoverlay/streetviewoverlay.htm
- http://projects.teammaps.com/projects/streetviewtour/tour.htm

I'm still looking for a solution, and I've found some nice libraries external to google services:

- http://leandigo.github.io/leanorama/  pretty nice, but looks like doesnt support firefox
- http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/markers.html - the best option imho

Indeed, using solution outside google's API has pro and cons - but this evalutation is up to you.

Comment: Actually I solved this problem months  ago with this tool    . https://github.com/marmat/google-maps-api-addons

Comment: @SaulBurgos its really nice! I've seen the volcano masaya tour on your site, may I ask you which library did you use in the end? Leanorama, photosphere viewer or those from teammaps?

Comment: I did not use any of those libraries. I just needed the library PanoMarker to create the hotspots inside my custom google streetviews.   The panoramas view are create by google street view with custom streetview method. nothing more.   I do not know if that answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be relevant:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays

It's an example of placing location markers on a street view map.
It defines the location of a place first, then defines the marker, giving it properties like icon and name.

```
var map;
var panorama;
var astorPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(40.729884, -73.990988);
var busStop = new google.maps.LatLng(40.729559678851025, -73.99074196815491);
var cafe = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730031233910694, -73.99142861366272);
var bank = new google.maps.LatLng(40.72968163306612, -73.9911389350891);

function initialize() {

  // Set up the map
  var mapOptions = {
    center: astorPlace,
    zoom: 18,
    streetViewControl: false
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Setup the markers on the map
  var cafeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: cafe,
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|FFFF00',
      title: 'Cafe'
  });

  var bankMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: bank,
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=dollar|FFFF00',
      title: 'Bank'
  });

  var busMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: busStop,
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=bus|FFFF00',
      title: 'Bus Stop'
  });

  // We get the map's default panorama and set up some defaults.
  // Note that we don't yet set it visible.
  panorama = map.getStreetView();
  panorama.setPosition(astorPlace);
  panorama.setPov(/** @type {google.maps.StreetViewPov} */({
    heading: 265,
    pitch: 0
  }));
}

function toggleStreetView() {
  var toggle = panorama.getVisible();
  if (toggle == false) {
    panorama.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    panorama.setVisible(false);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer :) , I know about that example in the google documentation but if you see in the example I wrote "Night Walk", the items are located with height . for example: located exactly in a window, if you move the scene you can see that  items stay in that position. I do not know if I am clear. is not a simple marker with position , they also have height